# Explicit instantiation of function template using incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

The following:

```
template< typename >
struct S;

template< typename T >
S< T >& f (S< T >& s) {
    const typename S< T >::nested ignore;
    return s;
}

template S< char >& f (S< char >&);

template< typename >
struct S {
    struct nested { };
};
```

compiles with gcc, but not with clang:

```
$ clang -c /tmp/t.cpp
/tmp/t.cpp:6:20: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'S<char>'
    const typename S< T >::nested ignore;
                   ^
/tmp/t.cpp:10:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'f<char>' requested here
template S< char >& f (S< char >&);
                    ^
/tmp/t.cpp:2:8: note: template is declared here
struct S;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I believe clang to be right in that, at the point of instantiation, the function f refers an incomplete definition of S. OTOH, a later specialization of S might provide the correct definition that makes the dependent 'nested' well-formed. Any opinions?

Comment: There are two points of instantiations for `f<char>`: at the explicit instantiation definition, and at the end of the TU. Your code is ill-formed NDR per [temp.point]/p8; both compilers are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both compilers are correct.

[temp.point]/p6, 8:

> 6 An explicit instantiation definition is an instantiation point for
>   the specialization or specializations specified by the explicit
>   instantiation.
>
> 8 A specialization for a function template [...] may
>   have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and
>   in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any
>   such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation. [...] If two different points of instantiation
>   give a template specialization different meanings according to the one
>   definition rule (3.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

There are two points of instantiation for `f<char>`: at the explicit instantiation definition, and at the end of the TU. Because those two points of instantiation would result in different meanings (as lookup for `S<T>::nested` would yield different results), the program is ill-formed NDR.

Comment: With *NDR* the standard makes live too easy for compilers. Surely, diagnostic (as actually provided here by clang) is extremely helpful here.